# Title of story about living a long time by cleansing cellular mutations?

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi, biology

What is the name of a sci fi book about a man who gets his cellular damage/mutations reset? His wife cannot get it done because she had radiation for cancer when she was younger. Consequently, she gets older and eventually dies but the husband gets younger and marries someone else. I think he is able to have the cellular “cleansing” done again so he is able to live a long time. I probably read this book 20-30 years ago. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit recent (2007, so only 17 years ago), but [*Rollback*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?210881) by Robert Sawyer fits most of this.

The protagonist, Don Halifax, gets the titular rollback treatment because his much more important wife, astrophysicist Sarah Halifax, demands they both get it.  (She decodes a message from the stars and a billionaire funds their treatment so they are alive to see the response.)

It doesn't work on Sarah and she dies, while Don goes on to remarry with Sarah's former assistant Leonore.

Comment: Yes! That’s it! Thank you so much. 17 years - 20-30 years, it’s basically the same thing, which was a while ago. That idea in that book has always stuck with me and I’m waiting to see when we start doing rollbacks in our lifetime!

Comment: @AdrienneSmith please mark the answer as correct so we can close the question.